# how to know the number of rows of a table in python?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

I'm doing tests with selenium and wanted to print the number of rows in the table, but for some reason it's not working and gives me this error "TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()" how could I do for print the number of lines on the table?

```
    tabela = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table")
    tabela2 = len(tabela)
    print(tabela2)
```

Comment: Your call returns a single element, not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
    tabela = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table")
```

Try

```
    tabela = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table")
```

If this returns any elements, it will return an array of webelements, and you can iterate through them as you have.

Comment: thank you worked but why prints only one. My table has more than 10 elements

Comment: is there any method that counts the tr number of a table @C. Peck